# Using InkScape, Some svg file is not converted to png

Tags: svg, inkscape

I am using OS - Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS  And InkScape version : 0.92.3.

Mostly svg file properly converted to PNG. But in Some files, not converted properly.

Here is svg contents and file linked in it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="380" height="380" viewBox="0 0 380 380" xml:space="preserve">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.7.13</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="translate(190 190) scale(0.506667 0.506667)">
    <image xlink:href="1-original.jpg" x="-500" y="-375" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="1000" height="750" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Here](http://usadmn.canvaschamp.com/media/designtool/canvasprints/single-print/2018/09/6014/1-original.jpg) is link of original file which needs to download and save '1-original.jpg' within same directory where svg file is placed.

Then run command:

```
inkscape 6014.svg --export-png=demo.png
```

After run command and generated demo.png which is not properly generated:

[image: x]

While svg file open in browser it will be show proper.

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in inkscape, report it to inkscape's bugtracker.

Comment: While run command in terminal (inkscape 6014.svg --export-png=demo.png) , there is not given any error.  And show below message:

Background RRGGBBAA: ffffff00 Area 0:0:380:380 exported to 380 x 380 pixels (96 dpi) Bitmap saved as: demo.png

==>Also same case is working within OS - Windows 7 System + InkScape version 0.92.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but: Why are you using Inkscape to convert from jpg to png? It works for me, btw. (on Linux, that is)